# Splitting field of $X^2-2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, galois-theory, splitting-field

I have a question about the uniqueness of splitting field $L$ of polynomial $X^2-2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. By factorizing $X^2-2 = (X-a)(X-b)$, we know the splitting field is $L = \mathbb{Q}(a,b)$, and we can show $\mathbb{Q}(a,b) = \mathbb{Q}(a) = \mathbb{Q}(b)$. An obvious choice of $a$ would be $\sqrt{2}$.There is a proposition saying here any two splitting fields over $\mathbb{Q}$ of this polynomial are $\mathbb{Q}$-isomorphic, but another splitting field of this polynomial can be $L$ generated by two elements $u,v$ unrelated to $a,b$, so I am wondering if there exists an isomorphism $\phi: \mathbb{Q}(a,b)\rightarrow \mathbb{Q}(u,v)$ which is not the identity map? Or there is only one possibility of $\phi$?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, there does exist an isomorphism between $\mathbb{Q}(a,b)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(u,v)$, which doesn't need to be the identity. (see [here](https://websites.math.leidenuniv.nl/algebra/algebra3eng.pdf), theorem $21.16$ on page $15$)

Comment: It's important to note that a splitting field is unique inside every algebraic closure. If you take a different algebraic closure, the splitting field will be a totally different field (with possibly different roots of the polynomial), and in this case the identity map makes no sense at all.

Comment: It is also possible that $\Bbb{Q}(a,b)$ and $\Bbb{Q}(u,v)$ are two different sets. For example, we could have $\Bbb{Q}(a,b)\subseteq\Bbb{R}$ with $a=\sqrt2$, $b=-\sqrt2$. And we can also have $L=\Bbb{Q}[X]/(X^2-2)$, which has, a priori, relatively little to do with real numbers. We would then have $u=X+(X^2-2)$ and $v=-X+(X^2-2)$. Still we have an isomorphism between $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$ and $L$ as promised by the uniqueness (up to isomorphism) of the splitting field. Actually two isomorphsims, because $a$ can be mapped to either $u$ or $v$.

Answer (score 1):

There are exactly *two* possibilties for $\varphi$ and that is because there are two automorphisms of ${\mathbb Q}(\sqrt2)$, namely the identity and the one that sends $\sqrt2$ to $-\sqrt2$.

Comment: You seem to assume that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ is the only splitting field of $X^2-2$. The comments have shown that this is just not true.

Comment: I did try to formulate my answer carefully so it works even if the OP is not (implicitly) working within a single algebraic closure. It is unclear to me if the OPs question is really about the existence of multiple (isomorphic) splitting fields or about multiple automorphism between two (equal or unequal) splitting fields.